# Deployment script - Remove checkbox Alwasy re-create database

Tags: deployment, sql-server-data-tools

This checkbox always makes me nervous. Is there anyway to completely remove the checkbox? I know its unchecked by default, but i would feel better if i knew that anyone cant check it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the checkbox and this really comes down to automating what you do and not giving people permissions to do something by mistake :)

1 - Automate Deployments

If you are deploying to databases other than developer specific instances then stop, developers in visual studio should only be able to "break" their own machines and private databases which is fine as they can fix them themselves.

To deploy to other environments (test, qa, prod etc) then you shouldn't be using visual studio as it is too easy to make mistakes, instead take the dacpac that is the output from ssdt and have a script call sqlpackage.exe with the correct argumments to deploy it - ideally this would be done on a build server as part of a build.

If you do this then no one can accidentally click that box, which I agree sounds scary :)

2 - Permissions

Secondly you need to make sure that developers (or anyone) doesn't have permission to accidentally deploy to the wrong server by restricting permissions. If you do not do this you are asking for trouble (most likely accidental but trouble nonetheless).

Hope it helps :)

ed